# Logarithmic scale in Excel chart with non-transformed axis labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'd like to change a plot so that the y-axis has a logarithmic scale. But when you check the box "logarithmic scale" it also transforms the axis labels.

I would like to have the axis show only untransformed labels, e.g. 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, with corresponding gridlines, but have these spaced such that the scale is logarithmic (i.e. the distance between 1.0 and 1.5 is greater than the distance between 1.5 and 2.0)

Is there any way of doing this? I found this way of creating a ['fake axis'](http://peltiertech.com/custom-axis-y-1-2-4-8-16/) but this is really a hack and I was wondering if anyone knows a better way?

Comment: There's no built-in way that I know of (and I've done a lot of log charting).  My experience with Excel is that "hacking" is the best way-I basically consider it part of the user experience.  Also, if Jon Peltier has a work-around, a native Excel solution probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @dav. I believe you, and I guess I'll just have to enjoy the experience :)